# Erro com append com arquivo csv em python

Tags: python, csv, append

tenho um código que envia informações para um aquivo *csv*. Quando ele executa a primeira vez ele escreve o arquivo normalmente, mas quando ele é executado pela segunda vez, que deveria adicionar uma nova linha no arquivo ele acaba sobrescrevendo o arquivo todo:

```
        with open('\\offline.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
        try:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow((hw_Processador(), hw_Fabricante_PlacaMae(), hw_Modelo_PlacaMae(), hw_NS_PlacaMae(), sis_HostName(), sis_SistemaOperacional(), sis_Data_Instalacao(), sis_Dominio(), sis_Arquitetura(), sis_Usuario_Atual(), rede_IPV4(), rede_MacAddress(), rede_DNS(), hw_Memoria_RAM(), hw_HD(), nome_tecnico, local_mapeamento))
            print('SEM CONEXAO! ARQUIVO CSV GERADO.')
        finally:
            f.close()
```

Alguém teria ideia do que poderia estar acontecendo?

Comment: Pelo o que [testei aqui](https://repl.it/@acwoss/InfiniteShoddyMegabyte) o código está funcionando normalmente. Consegue elaborar um [mcve]?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss estava fazendo o minimal reproducible example e descobri o erro durante o processo. Muito obrigado, era uma função dentro do meu código.

Comment: @AlgeuJunior Você poderia colocar a resposta do problema.

Answer (score -2):

```py
 with open('\\offline.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
```

Busque fazer essa linha sem o `newline`:

```py
 with open('\\offline.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Comment: Por qual motivo?